# GPU processing in Julia with minimal changes

Tags: machine-learning, julia, gpu

Is there a possibility to execute your julia ML code in GPU without intensive editing?

Comment: Yes, there is :)

Comment: May i ask for any articles or tutorials suggestion, on how this can be implemented?

Comment: Example: https://github.com/crstnbr/JuliaOulu20/blob/master/backup/gpu/gpu.ipynb